# How to Access Twitter App with another account?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I created a Twitter App in order to control a specified account (post tweet, etc).
I created this app with my personal account so I can only post tweets on my personal account.
I'd like to share permissions with my other account so I can tweet on it.

I heard about OAuth but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `twurl` to authenticate to another account. The account token and secret will be stored in the `.twurlrc` file in your home directory, you can use those to post from another account.